# Convert T-SQL command to lambda expression

Tags: sql, linq, lambda

Please help me to convert the following command to lambda equivalent

```
Select t1.id, t1.fullname 
From t1 
Where t1.id in (Select t2.id From t2 Where t2.bNo = 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use linq `where` with `Any`.

```
var result = t1.Where(x => t2.Any(x1 => x1.Id == x.Id && x1.bNo == 5))
                  .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.fullName });
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xUq3im)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `contains` in your expression.

```
var IdListQuery = context.t2.where(c=> c.bNo == 5).select(s=> s.id);
var query = context.t1.where(c=>IdListQuery.contains(c.id)).select(s=> s.id, s.fullname);
```